# Generalized eigenvalue with null space

Tags: eigenvalues, eigensystem, iterative-method, svd, krylov-method

Define $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as
$$S:=H+Q^\top V^{-1} Q.$$
$H,V$ are positive semidefinite.  Here, $H$, $Q$, and $V$ are large, dense matrices but they are *structured*:  I can write code for matrix-vector products (e.g. $x\mapsto Hx$) but computing $V^{-1}$ or the map $x\mapsto V^{-1}x$ would require iteration.

**Given a sparse, symmetric, positive definite matrix $M$, what is the best way to find the $k$ smallest eigenvalues of $S$ satisfying $Sx=\lambda Mx$?**

---

Note that this problem is equivalent to the expanded generalized eigenvalue problem
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
H &Q^\top\\Q  & -V
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\lambda
\begin{pmatrix}
M & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ z
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $z$ is an auxiliary variable.  This is nice because it's symmetric and does not contain $V^{-1}$, so I was hoping to use machinery for generalized eigenvalues.  But the right-hand side of this generalized problem is not invertible, which seems to prevent the use of usual eigenvalue iteration.

Comment: What about solving the for the inverse eigenvalues $Mx = (1/\lambda) Sx$?

Comment: Indeed. You already know that zero is not an eigenvalue of $S$, so there is no downside to turning the problem around.

Comment: There are two reasons.  One is that I *don't* know that zero isn't an eigenvalue of $S$ (in fact in my application I know that it is, but probably not with much multiplicity).  Here, $H$ and $V$ are only semidefinite.  But the more pertinent reason is that solving the problem you suggest requires inverse iteration, so, I'd have to invert $S$ in every step.  This is itself an expensive iterative process.  It seems we should be able to do this with only one "for loop."

Comment: Hi Justin. If V is not too huge, you may try to pre-factorize it, and you may be able to exploit its structure to pre-factorize it. How is it structured ? Another possibility is factorizing the right-hand side matrix in your expanded generalized eigenvalue problem (using LDLt factorization).

Comment: Hi Bruno!  Thanks for the idea :-) .  Sadly, we're constructing $V$ using boundary PDE methods where we never actually write down its elements (e.g. fast multipole).  All we can do is matrix-vector products, which are usually enough for eigenvalue problems, but not here it appears.  We *can* invert $M$, for what it's worth -- can even think of $M$ as diagonal.

Comment: If semi-definite you can't invert it no?

Comment: $M$ is positive definite (invertible), but the eigenproblem involves a larger matrix $\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, which is not invertible.

Comment: @JustinSolomon I am facing similar problem, trying to find the eigenvalues of linearized Navier-Stokes-Boussinesq model using Taylor-Hood elements. Did you find any good solution for this problem ?

Comment: Sadly we didn't find any great solution.  But we managed to work our way around it.  Perhaps since you're also working on PDE you have a similar scenario; our notes are here:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.07070.pdf

Comment: Would you mind describing the solution that you implemented in the published paper as an answer?